# Folder Creation Subtract file number?

Tags: bash, copy, rename, directory

I havent been able to find an answer that best suites my needs, and I appologize if someone is able to find it easily.
I have a script that works to move files into folders based on their names.  It worked perfectly until I realized that The files where missing their extension once I fixed this (another script was responsible for the file naming based on an email subject line) Once I fixed this problem It then started making a folder for each file.  Is there anyway I can make this script drop everything in the folder name before the first (.)

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
#folder script
#Benjamin D. Schran
MAIN_DIR=/PGHWH1/Photos
cd $MAIN_DIR
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f > SCRIPT_LOG1
find . -name '* *' | while read fname 

do
    new_fname=`echo $fname | tr " " "_"`

    if [ -e $new_fname ]
    then
            echo "File $new_fname already exists. Not replacing $fname"
    else
            echo "Creating new file $new_fname to replace $fname"
            mv "$fname" $new_fname
    fi
done
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  | while read file;
do
f=$(basename "$file")
    f1=${f%.*}
if [ -d "$f1" ];
 then
   mv "$f" "$f1"
 else   
mkdir "$f1"
chmod 777 "$f1"
mv "$f" "$f1"
fi
done

SCRIPTLOG=Script_log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
find . -type f > SCRIPT_LOG2
cd /PGHWH1/bin
sh scriptlog.sh > $SCRIPTLOG.html 
mv $SCRIPTLOG.html /PGHWH1/log
rm $MAIN_DIR/SCRIPT_LOG1 $MAIN_DIR/SCRIPT_LOG2
```

What I need it to do is to take a files that is

```
Filename-date.%.jpg
```

and make

```
Foldername-date
```

then move the files of

```
Filename-date.1.jpg
Filename-date.2.jpg
Filename-date.3.jpg
```

to the appropriate folder

```
Foldername-date
```

but the current output is

```
Foldername-date.1
Foldername-date.2
Foldername-date.3
```

Any help at all would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following lines do the job in my bash:

```
#first create a tmp file with unique directory names
ls *.jpg | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | uniq > dirs

#second create the directories
mkdir -p `cat dirs`

#third move the files
for i in `cat dirs`; do mv $i*.jpg $i/; done

#(optionally) remove the tmp file
rm dirs
```